# Filter query by checkbox categories

Tags: c#, sql, checkbox, where-clause

I have a database table with including four colums. 
These contains `answerOption` to question 1, 2, 3 and 4.
The answerOption can be a number from 1 to 5.

I want to have a table of 20 checkboxes so i can say that Q1 have to be 1 or 4 and Q4 have to be 3.

i guess I have to make some sort of `OnChecked` event (using ASP.NET), then construct there `Where` clause. My challange is this where clause. Are there any suggestions?

### Edit

I can give a little case so that everybody understands what I'm actually trying to achieve. I have a survey with four question and five different answerOptions. The survey is like:

1. How old are you?
2. Which part of the country do you live in?
3. How many kids do you have?
4. How muvh income do you have?

I want to present every question in one pie chart each and by default, everything should by shown. With the presentation you can see probability off how old an person is, where a person lives, how many kids a person have and income.

But I want to have checkboxes so i can view an 40 year old person, with good income, in the whole country. And see the given probability off how many kids he/her will have.

The goal of this tool is too find goal of bad situations.

Was this clear or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example using CheckBox based filtering. The WHERE clause is a bit long.

```
SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE
(
    @Q1AnswerOption1 | @Q1AnswerOption2 | @Q1AnswerOption3 | @Q1AnswerOption3 | @Q1AnswerOption4 | @Q1AnswerOption5 = 0
    OR Q1Answer = 1 * @Q1AnswerOption1 OR Q1Answer = 2 * @Q1AnswerOption2 OR Q1Answer = 3 * @Q1AnswerOption3 OR Q1Answer = 4 * @Q1AnswerOption4 OR Q1Answer = 5 * @Q1AnswerOption5
) AND (
    @Q2AnswerOption1 | @Q2AnswerOption2 | @Q2AnswerOption3 | @Q2AnswerOption3 | @Q2AnswerOption4 | @Q2AnswerOption5 = 0
    OR Q2Answer = 1 * @Q2AnswerOption1 OR Q2Answer = 2 * @Q2AnswerOption2 OR Q2Answer = 3 * @Q2AnswerOption3 OR Q2Answer = 4 * @Q2AnswerOption4 OR Q3Answer = 5 * @Q2AnswerOption5
) AND (
    @Q3AnswerOption1 | @Q3AnswerOption2 | @Q3AnswerOption3 | @Q3AnswerOption3 | @Q3AnswerOption4 | @Q3AnswerOption5 = 0
    OR Q3Answer = 1 * @Q3AnswerOption1 OR Q3Answer = 2 * @Q3AnswerOption2 OR Q3Answer = 3 * @Q3AnswerOption3 OR Q3Answer = 4 * @Q3AnswerOption4 OR Q3Answer = 5 * @Q3AnswerOption5
) AND (
    @Q4AnswerOption1 | @Q4AnswerOption2 | @Q4AnswerOption3 | @Q4AnswerOption3 | @Q4AnswerOption4 | @Q4AnswerOption5 = 0
    OR Q4Answer = 1 * @Q4AnswerOption1 OR Q4Answer = 2 * @Q4AnswerOption2 OR Q4Answer = 3 * @Q4AnswerOption3 OR Q4Answer = 4 * @Q4AnswerOption4 OR Q4Answer = 5 * @Q4AnswerOption5
)
```

**EDIT:**
The first part @Q1AnswerOption1 | @Q1AnswerOption2 | @Q1AnswerOption3 | @Q1AnswerOption3 | @Q1AnswerOption4 | @Q1AnswerOption5 = 0 is true when all the Q1 checkboxes are unchecked. In this case, the row is selected no matter what the Q1Answer is. If at least one checkbox is selected the first part is false and the second part selects only the matching rows.

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Form1.aspx.cs" Inherits="aspx_Form1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE (@Q1AnswerOption1 | @Q1AnswerOption2 | @Q1AnswerOption3 | @Q1AnswerOption3 | @Q1AnswerOption4 | @Q1AnswerOption5 = 0 OR Q1Answer = 1 * @Q1AnswerOption1 OR Q1Answer = 2 * @Q1AnswerOption2 OR Q1Answer = 3 * @Q1AnswerOption3 OR Q1Answer = 4 * @Q1AnswerOption4 OR Q1Answer = 5 * @Q1AnswerOption5) AND (@Q2AnswerOption1 | @Q2AnswerOption2 | @Q2AnswerOption3 | @Q2AnswerOption3 | @Q2AnswerOption4 | @Q2AnswerOption5 = 0 OR Q2Answer = 1 * @Q2AnswerOption1 OR Q2Answer = 2 * @Q2AnswerOption2 OR Q2Answer = 3 * @Q2AnswerOption3 OR Q2Answer = 4 * @Q2AnswerOption4 OR Q3Answer = 5 * @Q2AnswerOption5) AND (@Q3AnswerOption1 | @Q3AnswerOption2 | @Q3AnswerOption3 | @Q3AnswerOption3 | @Q3AnswerOption4 | @Q3AnswerOption5 = 0 OR Q3Answer = 1 * @Q3AnswerOption1 OR Q3Answer = 2 * @Q3AnswerOption2 OR Q3Answer = 3 * @Q3AnswerOption3 OR Q3Answer = 4 * @Q3AnswerOption4 OR Q3Answer = 5 * @Q3AnswerOption5) AND (@Q4AnswerOption1 | @Q4AnswerOption2 | @Q4AnswerOption3 | @Q4AnswerOption3 | @Q4AnswerOption4 | @Q4AnswerOption5 = 0 OR Q4Answer = 1 * @Q4AnswerOption1 OR Q4Answer = 2 * @Q4AnswerOption2 OR Q4Answer = 3 * @Q4AnswerOption3 OR Q4Answer = 4 * @Q4AnswerOption4 OR Q4Answer = 5 * @Q4AnswerOption5)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q1AnswerOption1CheckBox" Name="Q1AnswerOption1" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q1AnswerOption2CheckBox" Name="Q1AnswerOption2" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q1AnswerOption3CheckBox" Name="Q1AnswerOption3" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q1AnswerOption4CheckBox" Name="Q1AnswerOption4" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q1AnswerOption5CheckBox" Name="Q1AnswerOption5" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />

                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q2AnswerOption1CheckBox" Name="Q2AnswerOption1" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q2AnswerOption2CheckBox" Name="Q2AnswerOption2" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q2AnswerOption3CheckBox" Name="Q2AnswerOption3" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q2AnswerOption4CheckBox" Name="Q2AnswerOption4" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q2AnswerOption5CheckBox" Name="Q2AnswerOption5" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />

                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q3AnswerOption1CheckBox" Name="Q3AnswerOption1" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q3AnswerOption2CheckBox" Name="Q3AnswerOption2" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q3AnswerOption3CheckBox" Name="Q3AnswerOption3" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q3AnswerOption4CheckBox" Name="Q3AnswerOption4" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q3AnswerOption5CheckBox" Name="Q3AnswerOption5" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />

                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q4AnswerOption1CheckBox" Name="Q4AnswerOption1" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q4AnswerOption2CheckBox" Name="Q4AnswerOption2" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q4AnswerOption3CheckBox" Name="Q4AnswerOption3" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q4AnswerOption4CheckBox" Name="Q4AnswerOption4" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Q4AnswerOption5CheckBox" Name="Q4AnswerOption5" PropertyName="Checked" Type="Byte" DefaultValue="0" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            Question 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q1AnswerOption1CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption1" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q1AnswerOption2CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption2" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q1AnswerOption3CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption3" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q1AnswerOption4CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption4" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q1AnswerOption5CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption5" AutoPostBack="True" />
            <br />
            Question 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q2AnswerOption1CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption1" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q2AnswerOption2CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption2" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q2AnswerOption3CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption3" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q2AnswerOption4CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption4" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q2AnswerOption5CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption5" AutoPostBack="True" />
            <br />

            Question 3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q3AnswerOption1CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption1" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q3AnswerOption2CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption2" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q3AnswerOption3CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption3" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q3AnswerOption4CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption4" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q3AnswerOption5CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption5" AutoPostBack="True" />
            <br />

            Question 4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q4AnswerOption1CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption1" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q4AnswerOption2CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption2" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q4AnswerOption3CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption3" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q4AnswerOption4CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption4" AutoPostBack="True" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Q4AnswerOption5CheckBox" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption5" AutoPostBack="True" />
            <br />

            <br />
            Answers<br />
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: #FFF8DC;">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q1AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q1Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q2AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q2Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q3AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q3Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q4AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q4Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: #008A8C; color: #FFFFFF;">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="IdLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Q1AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q1Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Q2AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q2Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Q3AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q3Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Q4AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q4Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>No data was returned.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="IdTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Q1AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q1Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Q2AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q2Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Q3AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q3Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Q4AnswerTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q4Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q1AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q1Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q2AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q2Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q3AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q3Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q4AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q4Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table runat="server">
                        <tr runat="server">
                            <td runat="server">
                                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                    <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                                        <th runat="server">Id</th>
                                        <th runat="server">Q1Answer</th>
                                        <th runat="server">Q2Answer</th>
                                        <th runat="server">Q3Answer</th>
                                        <th runat="server">Q4Answer</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr runat="server">
                            <td runat="server" style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="background-color: #008A8C; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q1AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q1Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q2AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q2Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q3AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q3Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Q4AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q4Answer") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the use of @. Is this code meant to be in codebehind or in a sqldatasource in markup file? And to get boolean value from checkbox, do i need any attribut in c#? If i don't specify anything for Q4, will I then get everything for that question?

Comment: Did my case, make my problem more meaningful. Since I want colums of checkboxes, I think I will go for independent checkboxes instead of checkboxlist. My concern with your suggestion is that if I don't check any options for one question, it wont show anything, but itshould show eveything.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is very good. But something that I think is a little unclear, is how your were clause works. 

The new part, does that say: take only values equal 0, therefore nothing. And if you have checked at least one checkbox, it will use the second part of the clause, and give exactly result of every option that you have entered?

Comment: The point i tried to bring up with my case is that, if I decide option for one question, i

Comment: The point I tried to bring up with my case, is that if I choose one option for one question, I want to see every record that matches this. And not requir to decide option for every question. But I've understood your point and I think it should be something like this:

Comment: I'm sorry, now I can see this is the solution to my problem! Thanks a lot!